# error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'InputValue' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and c# language, I found this error, can anyone help me to solve this?

this is my script code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputValue;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 1f;
    public float collisionOffset = 0.05f;
    public ContactFilter2D movementFilter;

    Vector2 movementInput;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    List<RaycastHit2D> castCollisions = new List<RaycastHit2D>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (movementInput != Vector2.zero)
        {
            int count = rb.Cast(
                movementInput,
                movementFilter,
                castCollisions,
                moveSpeed = Time.fixedDeltaTime + collisionOffset
            );
        }
    }

    void onMove(InputValue movementValue)
    {
        movementInput = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();
    }
}
```

I'm new to C#, I haven't set up the C# language, like the compiler, etc. Does this matter?, isn't that all included in the unity installation?

Answer (score 0):

`using UnityEngine.InputValue;` should be `using UnityEngine.InputSystem;` and you need to install "Input System" from the Package Manager (Window > Package Manager).